# "[key in Keys]" works but not with any other extra key?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Can someone explain me this ?

Typescript can detect clashes if same keys in an object. Then why extra keys are not allowed ?

[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA0hIGcoF4oCICMaoB90CZs80BmI9AFnLQFY0BuAKEYHoWoB1AewCcBrBI1CQoAMS5cUUAN6Mo8qAG0+8KAEsAdrHgIAugC4oCYD00BzJvIC+TVuwCiPHr0HDoAIQCGPKdIVQ5BQgADxNPOBAoQ2NTDQtA+WVVTW1EAyMTcyYrIXBoAClvX38EpRVIlIi9aMy4yyDQnnDVGtj4qyA)

```
type Keys = "1" | "2" | "3" | "4" | "5";

// Works
type Foo = {
    [key in Keys]: string;
  };

// Errors
type Bar = {    
    extraKey : string;
    [key in Keys]: string;
}
type Jar = {    
    [key in Keys]: string;
    extraKey : string;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't add fields in such way to [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html), but you can use an intersection:

```
type Bar = {    
    extraKey : string;
} & {
    [key in Keys]: string;
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA0hIGcoF4oCICMaoB90CZs80BmI9AFnLQFY0BuAKEdEigDEB7TlKAb0ZQhUANoBreFACWAO1jwEAXQBcUBMABOsgOZMAvkxbhoAIQCGG3gOFQIAD01m4IVeq0zdjPVABk-QcLikrLyiCpqmjr6QA)

Answer (score 0):

Since `extraKey` also has string value, following should work

```
type Bar = {    
    [key in Keys | "extraKey"]: string;
}
```

Comment: I made the example shorter. Actually it's can be of any type not necessary string. I can't keep giving unions.